# Button click event not capturing right element

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE QUESTION:
I'm asking my question wrong!!!
How do I capture the click event of the current element in .each? should I assign the button ID = to the current eq: of the row and then find a way to refer to it in the click event?

or should I be looking at changing: `FDID: $('.fdid-1').val()` to something like: `FDID: $('this.fdid-1').val()`

---

dynamic form elements with button, click event not capturing the form ul containing the button. code will send json to php page for processing. Using "document" gets the full page, need to drill down deeper into elements.

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
alert($(this).text());

var form_data = {
    FDID: $('.fdid-1').val(),
    CHOICE1: $('.choice-1').val(),
    CHOICE2: $(".choice-2").val()
    };      

$.getJSON("modify.php",form_data,function(data){
    switch(data.retval){
        case 0: $("#status").html("Update successful!");
        break;
        case 1: $("#status").html("Unable to update!");
        break;
        default: $("#description").html("Database error, please try again.");
        break;
        }
});
});

$.each( data, function ( i, val ) {

        ($('<div>')
        .attr({
            'data-role': 'collapsible',
            'data-content-theme': 'c',
            'data-collapsed': 'true',
            'id': 'cResults'
        })
        .html('<h4>' + this.LastName + ', ' + this.FirstName + '</h4>'
        + '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Choices..." data-inset="true" class="makecollapsibleul">'
        + '<li><form id="productForm" action="modify.php" method="post">'
        + '<label for="fdid-1">FDID:</label>'
        + '<input type="text" name="fdid-1" class="fdid-1" value=' + this.FDID + '>'
        + '</li><li>' 
        + '<label for="text-1">Choice 1:</label>'
        + '<input type="text" name="choice-1" class="choice-1" value=' + this.C1 + '>'
        + '</li><li>' 
        + '<label for="text-2">Choice 2:</label>'
        + '<input type="text" name="choice-2" class="choice-2" value=' + this.C2 + '>'
        + '</li><li>' 
        + 'IP: ' + this.IPADDRESS + '</li><input type="submit" class="submit" value="UPDATE" /></form><li>' 
        + 'Pick Date: ' + this.PICKDATE + '</li>'
        + '</ul>'))
        .appendTo('#primary');

                //$(".title").append('<li>'+orderNum+' -- '+itemNum+'</li>');

        $('#makecollapsible').collapsibleset().trigger('create');
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

HTML:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="main">      
    <div data-role="header">         
        <h1>JSON DATA</h1>     
    </div><!-- /header -->      

    <div data-role="content">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="description"></div>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="outer-ul">
        <li>  
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Submitted Choices</h4> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="makecollapsible">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>           
    </div><!-- /content -->      

    <div data-role="footer">              
    </div>

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML as well?

Comment: most is dynamic and in provided code, ill post the html as well

Comment: What if you replace `document` with something else, e.g. `#outer-ul`, is this what you are meaning? Also, I assume `data` is set elsewhere for your `$.each` function as the `$.getJSON` function is closed before the start of the `$.each` function.

Comment: #outer-ul is a fixed element, the .each are 100's of rows and each is different, the click event is picking up on the first row, not the row containing the button.

Comment: So what happens when you click the `.submit` button currently? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: same results, only gets the FDID of the first row in .each every time regardless of the row the button is clicked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use the post from within my ul to handle data - not sure why I can't get it directly from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have more than one element on the page with the same class or ID? This would cause you to get the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code after all the elements is loaded:

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
 ... 
});
```

**Tip:** try to avoid mixing html tags into strings and adding the data form the server, you may use a template engine instead. (like jquery templates...).

Comment: tried that, dynamic content needs the .on function, the current $(document).on allows the click event to fire, the `$('.submit').click will not reach within the collapsible div

Answer (score 0):

When you clikc on the submit button you should find the inputs from your form that has the clicked button.

If you have multiple inputs with same class, `$(".myClass").val()` will return the first element value.

So, the solution is to get the form and find the inputs inside of the form:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    //event.stopPropagation();
    var form_data = {
        FDID: $('.fdid-1', $form).val(),
        CHOICE1: $('.choice-1', $form).val(),
        CHOICE2: $(".choice-2", $form).val()
    };
});
```